Why does symfony use my custom not autoconfigured serializer?
I have symfony 6.4 application.
I registered my custom serializer in services.yml.
    object_normalizer_with_snake_case_name_converter:
        parent: 'serializer.normalizer.object'
        arguments:
            $nameConverter: '@serializer.name_converter.camel_case_to_snake_case'
        autoconfigure: false

    serializer_with_snake_case_name_converter:
        class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer
        factory: ['@App\Serializer\SerializerFactory', 'createWithCamelCaseToSnakeCaseConverter']
        autoconfigure: false

I have 2 questions:

Why does symfony use my serializer_with_snake_case_name_converter in serializer.denormalizer.array?
Is it possible to register serializer with CamelCaseToSnakeCaseConverter in service container so I would use it only in services where I need it (for example in ApiClient)?

What I did:
I used serializer_with_snake_case_name_converter in my controller and symfony started using it in serializer.denormalizer.array.
But when I inject also default symfony serializer into controller, then everything become ok, symfony doesn't use my custom serializer.
I can't understand why symfony does it and where I am wrong. I registered my custom serializer as not autoconfigured (autoconfigure: false) and expected that I could use it only by service name.

In this example $arrayDenormalizer->denormalizer->normalizers[13]->nameConverted == MetadataAwareNameConverter.

    #[Route('/', name: 'app_test')]
    public function index(
        #[Autowire(service: 'serializer_with_snake_case_name_converter')]
        SerializerInterface $serializerWithSnakeCaseNameConverter,
        SerializerInterface $defaultSerializer,
        #[Autowire(service: 'serializer.denormalizer.array')]
        ArrayDenormalizer $arrayDenormalizer,
    ): Response
    {
        dd($arrayDenormalizer);
    }


In this example $arrayDenormalizer->denormalizer->normalizers[13]->nameConverted == CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter, but I expect MetadataAwareNameConverter here.

    #[Route('/', name: 'app_test')]
    public function index(
        #[Autowire(service: 'serializer_with_snake_case_name_converter')]
        SerializerInterface $serializerWithSnakeCaseNameConverter,
        #[Autowire(service: 'serializer.denormalizer.array')]
        ArrayDenormalizer $arrayDenormalizer,
    ): Response
    {
        dd($arrayDenormalizer);
    }

